# How to use NSdate to format "Friday 5 Jul 2013"

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

hi i am useing `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter`, how can i show the date in format like this

Friday 5 Jul 2013

here is the code im using currently. please help.

```
NSString *MyString;
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    MyString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    date.text = MyString;
```

Comment: This is well documented throughout the internet. For instance: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 1):

Use like this..

```
    NSString *MyString;
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMM yyyy"];
    MyString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSLog(@"%@",MyString);
```

output is

```
Tuesday 17 Sep 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
NSDate * currentdate=[NSDate date];

    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter1=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"eeee dd MMM yyyy"];

    NSString * str=[dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:currentdate];

    NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Output is below

```
Tuesday 17 Sep 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this format

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"eeee-dd-MMM-yyyy"];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE,dd MMMM yyyy"];
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i tested  this code:

```
   NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE d MMM  yyyy"];
    NSString  *MyString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSLog(@"%@",MyString);
```

**output**

Tuesday 17 Sep  2013